# How do I create a plural translation using Twig and the i18n extension?

Tags: internationalization, twig, slim, gettext, twig-extension

I'm using the Slim PHP framework with Twig and the Twig extension i18n. I need to create a plural translation that displays the number of messages in an array. I'm using a text editor to create the `.po` file and Poedit to compile it to a `.mo` file.

Here's my template:

```
        {% set count=messages|length %}
        {% trans %}
            Showing the last message.
        {% plural count %}
            Showing the last {{count}} messages.
        {% endtrans %}<br>
```

And here's my `.po` file (for Swedish translation):

```
msgid "Showing the last message."
msgid_plural "Showing the last %count messages."
msgstr[0] "Visar det senaste meddelandet."
msgstr[1] "Visar de %count senaste meddelandena."
```

This doesn't work, it gives me

```
Visar de %count senaste meddelandena.
```

even when `count` is 16.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Should that be `%count%` instead of `%count`? The [documentation](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html) has this example: "During the gettext lookup these placeholders are converted. `{{ name }}` becomes `%name%` so the gettext `msgid` for this string would be `Hello %name%!`."

Comment: @martias You're right, just replacing `%count` with `%count%` worked! I missed that paragraph in the documentation, and the template I used was a demo from some online-po-edit-site which used `%s` in the example, so I just assumed that was the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `%count` should instead be `%count%`. The [documentation of the i18n extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html) has this example:

> ```
> {% trans %}
>     Hello {{ name }}!
> {% endtrans %}
> ```
>
> During the gettext lookup these placeholders are converted. `{{ name }}` becomes `%name%` so the gettext `msgid` for this string would be `Hello %name%!`.

Answer (score -3):

[The documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates) propose the following usage

```
{% transchoice count %}
    {1} Showing the last message.|]1,Inf[ Showing the %count% messages.
{% endtranschoice %}
```

A more complex example:

```
{% transchoice count with {'%name%': 'Fabien'} from 'app' %}
    {0} %name%, there are no apples|{1} %name%, there is one apple|]1,Inf[ %name%, there are %count% apples
{% endtranschoice %}
```